# How do SMS senders (Companies) have a profile picture in SMS in REALME Messages App?

Tags: sms, realme

[image: 1]

I found nothing on the web regarding the same except [this thread.](https://support.google.com/voice/thread/1068515/how-do-i-set-a-profile-image-to-display-in-sms?hl=en) 
But from the thread, it seems like this is shown only when using Google Services which I apparently am not (And it's for common people too not just company SMS'. So most probably those are just locally set pics or Gmail's pics).

So how are these profile pictures coming from? I'm guessing it is the website's logo maybe. It has a data usage of 75KB in the last month. Are additional data conveyed when sending an SMS (like website, phone, address, etc) Can I set one of mine too?

I don't have much knowledge of this. Correct me if I'm wrong
Regards

Comment: I think this depends on the Messaging app used. Some have additional features like caller ID. They may also have their own sources for the image. You might want to try changing the Messaging app and see whether the same image is shown or not.

Comment: @AndrewT. Sorry for the late reply. I tried Google Messages and a couple more messaging apps. Turns out it was just a feature of Realme Messages App. This question makes no sense now. I should delete it

Comment: IMO, the question make sense. It is a reasonable question. A person could be curious about the issue you mentioned. Andrew's comment gives pointer to satisfy that curiosity. You can self-answer this question it or you can delete it if you still deem the question unhelpful.